# Routing traffic destined to a specific IP to a nested VM

Tags: vpn, routing, azure

We are using a service to clone a live DC to a nested VM in MS Azure that functions as a failover. The DC has the IP `192.169.0.2`, so of course the nested VM in Azure also has the IP of `192.168.0.2`. We have a site to site VPN set up between our site and Azure. The Azure network is using `10.x.x.x.`. In the event that they on-prem DC fails, we will need to route traffic to the nested VM in Azure.

How would we go about doing this? Should the Azure subnet match the on-prem subnet of `192.x.x.x`, or would it make more sense to set up routing rules that state "Send traffic destined for `192.168.0.2` to [Azure Gateway Subnet] and then an Azure routing table pointing to the Hypervisor?

The idea is we want to be able to quickly and efficiently transition users from the on-prem DC to the Azure nested copy of the DC in the event of failure, and I am not sure what best practices are, or what the most efficient way to implement this would be.

Thank you ahead of time for the advice. I am new to Azure and fairly new to enterprise routing as a whole.

Comment: wait, you're saying you intentionally gave the same IP address to multiple endpoints?

Comment: @sippybear Both devices are not live. The software that is providing the backup is cloning the DC, so the nested VM has the same IP as the live DC, but is powered down. Hopefully, this machine will never need to spin up, but I need to ensure that we can seamlessly move from using the DC on their local subnet, to the one that is on the VPN.